# how to show a second component in top of page and make scroll to up to show a first component React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, scrollview

```
Import React from "react";
export default Layout() {
 return (
<div>
  <aside> side left bar </aside>
  <aside> side right bar </aside>
  <main> 
   <navBar/> 
   <FirstComponent /> // hidden 
   <SecondComponent />
  </main>
<div>
)
}
```

when layout render show a secondComponent at the top of mainContent and make user to scroll up to show a first component

Comment: Do you want to render a scroll back to top button? [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp) might help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.